# Custom object is not editable

Tags: object

I have created a custom object named "Product" with a lot of different fields, but for some reason I can't edit them. Even if I am creating a new product inside the list I can put only "name" field, everything else is blocked.

I have a Salesforce Developers edition, I guess my role is System Administrator and looks like I gave myself every allowance about editing this object. Some screenshots inside.[image: What I have when creating a new window]
[image: Permissions I gave myself]

[image: This is my ProductList how it looks like]

Comment: Did you add your fields to the page layout(s) when you created the fields? One way to figure that out is to create a record and then go to the record detail page. If you don't see any of the fields on the detail page, then they're not included in the page layout.

Comment: Hello, yes, they are in layout.

I can add some new stuff via importing in with CSV. 

I tried to create another custom object and upload information with code, but now I am getting an error: "You don't have access to this record. Ask your administrator for help or to request access."

Comment: You said, "I **guess** my role is System Administrator" [emphasis added by me]. I suggest starting with explicitly verifying whether that is true.

Comment: Also, there is a Standard (OOB) Object called/labelled _Product_, with an API Name of **Product2**.  Have you verified that in every place that you are intending to use and reference your **Product__c** object, that in one or more of them you are not accidentally using the **Product2** object?